Question about Proposition 2.11 Neukirch
I have been reading the proof of this proposition 2.11 from chapter I of Neukirch's algebraic number theory,
the proposition is the following:

(2.11) Proposition. Let $L\mid K$ and $L'\mid K$ be two Galois extensions of degree $n$, resp. $n'$, such that $L \cap L' = K$. Let $\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n$, resp. $\omega'_1, \ldots, \omega'_{n'}$, be an integral basis of $L \mid K$, resp. $L' \mid K$, with discriminant $d$, resp. $d'$. Suppose that $d$ and $d'$ are relatively prime in the sense that $xd + x'd' = 1$, for suitable $x, x' \in A$. Then $\omega_i \omega'_j$ is an integral basis of $LL'$, of discriminant $d^{n'} d'^n$.

but I have a doubt about the next step:

Write $T^*$ for the adjoint matrix of $T$. Then row-column expansion (2.3) gives
\begin{equation}
\det(T) b = T^* a.
\end{equation}
Since $T^*$ and $a$ have integral entries in $LL'$, the multiple $d'b$ has integral entries in $L$, namely $d' \beta_j = \sum_i d' a_{ij} \omega_i$. Thus $d' a_{ij} \in A$. Swapping the rôles of $(\omega_i)$ and $(\omega'_j)$, one checks in the same manner that $da_{ij} \in A$, so that
\begin{equation}
a_{ij} = xda_{ij} + x'd'a_{ij} \in A.
\end{equation}

How do we know that the elements of the adjoint are integrals in $LL'$? and also How do I conclude that $d'b$ has integral element entries in $L$?

Please do not use images to convey critical mathematical information that is not otherwise present in your post. Here are some of the reasons why.

Since $\omega'_j$ is integral over $A$ it satisfies a monic polynomial with coefficients in $A$.  Since $\sigma'_\ell \in G(LL'|L)$, it leaves $A$ fixed and so  $\sigma'_\ell\omega'_j$ is also integral over $A$, and so the entries of $T$ and the determinant of $T$ and the adjoint $T^*$ are all integral over $A$.
Using the same reasoning as above, the elements $\sigma'_i\alpha$ of $a$ are integral and therefore so are the elements of $T^*a$. Since $\det(T)^2 = d'$ and $\det(T)b = T^*a$, then $d'b = \det(T) \det(T)b = \det(T)T^*a$ is a vector all of whose elements are integral over $A$.
